# How to make mail indicator show a number

Tags: 12.04, indicator, mail

I was wondering if it's possible to make the mail indicator show the number of received messages and/or e-mails somewhat like Skype is already doing.

It's showing a color (blue) at the moment but I'd like for it to show a number when I for example receive messages instead of it changing colors. Is this possible?

I was wondering if it's possible to customize this icon as well, all I was able to find were different colors, but are there icon sets out there that have an idle icon and a new icon for when I receive messages? The reason I want this is because I think the blue color (or any other color) don't really match the Ubuntu theme.

Best Regards,
Hexicidal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using email client supporting such feature?

AFAIR it is supported by

- `kmail`
- `thunderbird` / `icedove` with `FireTray` plugin